# Angularjs Add and Remove Custom Directive validation based on other element

Tags: angularjs, validation, angular-directive

i have created custom validation "validateSprequired" using custom directive.

i need to validate element based on checkbox, if checkbox is checked i need to ignore validation if check box is not checked i need to validate element with custom validation.

i tried to use if condition on html and javascript also but i am not able to remove activate and deactivate custom validation.

my HTML

```
<input name="checkboxes" ng-model="vm.Assessment.infoOnly" id="checkboxes-0"
       type="checkbox"  value="true" ng-click="vm.isInfoOnly($event)">

<input name="peoplepicker" id="peoplepicker" validate-sppprequired="true" 
       type="text" ng-model="vm.Assessment.AssessmentDueDate">
```

Controller Code

```
 vm.isInfoOnly = function (event) {     
    var elem = $("#peoplepicker");
    if (event.target.checked) {            
        elem.attr('validate-sppprequired', false);              
        elem.removeAttr("validate-sppprequired");
        vm.Assessment.LeadCommentator.errors.validateSppprequired == true;  --> not working
    } else {               
        elem.attr('validate-sppprequired', true);              
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $compile(elem)($scope);
        });
    });
}
```

my directive

```
mainApp.directive('validateSppprequired', function ($compile) {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',     
        scope: {
            ngModel: '=',  
            validateSppprequired: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {

            if (attributes.validateSppprequired == "false") {
                                                   -->not working
                ngModel.$validators.validateSppprequired = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                    return true;
                }
                //ngModel.$validators.validateSppprequired = true; --> not working
                //ngModel.$setValidity("validateSppprequired", true); --> not working
                ngModel.$validate();
                return true;
            } else {
                ngModel.$validators.validateSppprequired = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                    if (ngModel.$isEmpty(modelValue) || modelValue.length == 0) {
                        return false;
                    } else {                       
                        return true;
                    }
                    return false; 
                };
            }
        }
    };
});
```

my requirement is if check box is checked this custom validation has to clear, if check box is not checked this custom validation has to apply.

if i start typing text in peoplepicker text this validation is working but with checkbox change its not working

angularjs is adding both "ng-valid" "ng-invalid" css class on checkbox changed event so angularjs always treated as invalid only

on checkbox checked event angularjs adding below css to textbox

```
ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-isolate-scope ng-invalid ng-invalid-validate-sppprequired ng-valid ng-scope ng-valid-validate-sppprequired
```

on checkbox un-checked event angularjs adding below css to textbox

```
ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-isolate-scope ng-invalid ng-invalid-validate-sppprequired ng-scope ng-valid-validate-sppprequired
```

in angularjs is there any way we can enable and disable custom validation from directive.

Answer (score 0):

You may use **ng-if** like this :

```
<input name="peoplepicker" id="peoplepicker" validate-sppprequired="true"
       type="text" ng-model="vm.Assessment.AssessmentDueDate" 
       ng-if="vm.Assessment.infoOnly">

<input name="peoplepicker" id="peoplepicker" validate-sppprequired="false" 
       type="text" ng-model="vm.Assessment.AssessmentDueDate"
       ng-if="!vm.Assessment.infoOnly">
```

or in place of ng-if you may also use **ng-show/ng-hide**. Use as per your requirement.
Now you don't have to use validation in JS.
Please let me know if this works.

Comment: i tried ng-show/ng-hide also control is hiding but still validation is running,

Comment: problem is validate-sppprequired="false" this custom validation is running and returning true from directive but angularjs adding both "ng-valid" and "ng-invalid" css tags, its not removing "ng-invalid" css class and not updating scope so its treating always ng-invalid

Comment: its showing textbox based on "vm.Assessment.infoOnly" but textbox became readonly and validation not working properly.